# angular-slickgrid, trigger the cell edit on select editor change event

Tags: javascript, angular, slickgrid

I am using angular-silkgrid with angular 7. I am using inline editing feature. I am using single select editor for inline edit. Currently I want to achieve this functionality:

As soon as user click on the editable field , the select drop down will be visible.On select any option from select dropdown the inline mode should exist and column value should be updated.

currently I need to click on other field to exit from inline mode(I want to achieve this on select option select)

```js
editor: {
  // display checkmark icon when True
  enableRenderHtml: true,
  // tslint:disable-next-line:max-line-length
  collection: [{
    value: 1,
    label: 'Sucessful'
  }, {
    value: 2,
    label: 'Unsucessful'
  }],
  model: Editors.singleSelect, // CustomSelectEditor
  elementOptions: {
    autoAdjustDropPosition: false,
    onClick: (event, rr) => {
      // here i want to write some code which can trigger to grid to start update
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks All for the answers. I have solved my issue as below:

```
   editor: {
      enableRenderHtml: true,
      collection: [{ value: CCLStaus.Sucessfull, label: 'Sucessful' }, { value: CCLStaus.UnSucessfull, label: 'Unsucessful' }],
      model: Editors.singleSelect,// CustomSelectEditor
      elementOptions: {
        onClick: (event) => {
          const updateItem = this.angularSilkGrid.gridService.getDataItemByRowIndex(this.rowInEditMode);
          updateItem.status = +event.value;
          this.angularSilkGrid.gridService.updateItem(updateItem, { highlightRow: false });
          this.angularSilkGrid.gridService.renderGrid();
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally,

```
grid.getEditorLock().commitCurrentEdit()
```

will commit and close the editor.
Also, any of

```
grid.navigateRight()
grid.navigateLeft()
grid.navigateDown()
grid.navigateUp()
grid.navigateNext()
grid.navigatePrev()
```

will commit and exit gracefully. In the `select2` editor, you'll notice:

```
    this.init = function () {
      ...

      // Set focus back to select2 element on closing.
      $input.on('select2:close', function (e) {
        if ((e.params.originalSelect2Event && e.params.originalSelect2Event.data) 
        || e.params.key === 9) {
          // item was selected with ENTER or no selection with TAB
          args.grid.navigateNext();
        } else {
          // closed with no selection
          setTimeout(function () {
            $input.select2('focus');
          }, 100);
        }
      });
    };

    this.destroy = function () {
        $input.select2('destroy');
        $input.remove();
    };
```

, noting that `args.grid.navigateNext()` will commit and close the editor, including calling the `destroy()` method at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

From the Angular-Slickgrid [Editor Example](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/editor) there's a checkbox in the example to `auto commit` and that is a setting to you need to enable in your Grid Options

```
this.gridOptions = {
  autoEdit: true,
  autoCommitEdit: true,
}
```

The lib will internally call `grid.getEditorLock().commitCurrentEdit()` like Ben wrote in his answer, in Angular-Slickgrid you can just set the `autoCommitEdit` flag that I added.